# jQuery object array get an item as jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-selectors, javascript-objects

I have an array contains `jQuery` selectors :

```
var aa = $('a');
```

when this line fires, contains of `aa` is an object array filled with `[object HTMLAnchorElement]`, now I want to get an object from `aa` **as a jQuery object** without using this :

```
var mynewelm = $(aa[index]);
```

Is that even possible ?

*I DO KNOW I CAN USE SPECIFIC SELECTOR TO GET THAT OBJECT AS `JQUERY OBJECT` BUT I HAVE TO USE `aa`.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
var mynewelem = aa.eq(index);
```